# Is there a way to fix ReadTimed out error during installation process?

Tags: python, kivy

I've been trying to install all the requirements for learning Kivy via python but during the installation process I get Environment error mean while the root cause is read timed out error. System throws several similar warning messages before finally throwing error message.

[error message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Clq89.png)

Ive tried upgrading pip to latest version and browsed internet to fix connection timed out problem .

but I dont know the problem so instead of trying more ramdom solutions I ve got to ask you proffesionals

Answer (score 0):

First, use the `pip install Kivy==1.11.1` and if it is not working I recommend you create virtualenv and install the kivy dependencies.

To create the environment

```
pip install virtualenv
python -m virtualenv venvname
#Activate the virtual environment
venvname\Scripts\activate
#or in a bash terminal
source venvname/Scripts/activate
```

To install the kivy dependencies

```
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1.* kivy_deps.glew==0.1.*
python -m pip install kivy_deps.gstreamer==0.1.*
```

For Python 3.5+:

```
python -m pip install kivy_deps.angle==0.1.*
```

To install the kivy

```
python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1
#or
pip install Kivy==1.11.1
#or 
python -m pip install https://github.com/kivy-garden/graph/archive/master.zip
```

Also, add to your  pip.conf.

```
[global]
timeout = 60
index-url = https://kivy-garden.github.io/simple/
```

See also [this](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html) and [this](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.garden.html)

Comment: I've already installed and activated virutual environment and did face similar problems during installing it.  I also tried installing kivy dependencies but again I'm facing same Read Timed out error still worse I get this error every time I try to install something.

Comment: @AmitShrestha try to add `[global]
timeout = 60
index-url = https://kivy-garden.github.io/simple/` to pip.conf. and if it is not working, check your connection and firewall.